# How to upgrade the kernel of Xubuntu 15.04 Live CD to latest 4.1/4.0.6 version?

Tags: upgrade, kernel, 15.04, live-cd

I am trying to upgrade the kernel of Xubuntu 15.04 AMD64 live CD to the latest version available (4.1/4.0.6) so that I can try and install the same on hitherto unsupported hardware.

I am using the process outline [here](https://gist.github.com/praveenbm5/bea8171ff50e4114ec46).

Here I am installing the Kernel `.deb` files from Ubuntu Mainline archive in the `CHROOT` environment and removing the stock kernel using `dpkg`  and `apt-get`. But all my attempts have been unsuccessful so far.

The boot process fails after loading initramfs with - AuFS: unable to mount root file system.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why don't you simply download and install the packages as explained in https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds ? --- no need to remove old kernels; you can choose the right one in the boot options screen.

Comment: Hello Ramos.. All that is about installing new kernels on an existing system but I dont have an existing ubunutu installation on the system I am trying to use. I need to install one first and I cant install it unless the install disc can boot on it. For it to boot - I need the install disc to run the latest kernel. Hence all this fuss!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you will be happy by having a look at liveng.readthedocs.io and Open Secure-K OS on GitHub.

The full aim of the liveng project is to give the Community a set of best practices in order to turn a common Debian Linux live into a live(ng) operating system which features:

- native encrypted persistence;
- **kernel update (on a live ISO 9660 filesystem)**;
- UEFI, with UEFI Secure Boot compatibility, with a real efi partition.